# Does wire size matter? If so, how?

Tags: transformer, function, fabrication

I took the transformer from a microwave to make a spot welder. I cut the secondary wire out. Now I'm supposed to wrap a wire around the iron base. Primary wire is much smaller gauge than the secondary, about 1/3 the size. So when I wrap the secondary wire twice, there is not enough power, but 3 times is too much. I understand that 3 wraps primary and 30 wraps secondary will make it 10 times more, using the same size wire. What's the formula for different sized wires?

I've been all over the net and all info is basic. No discussion of wire size. Maybe there's reason for that?

Comment: Welcome! Are you aware of wire resistance? Please calculate your secondary current, secondary wire length and thus resistance. From there, calculate your secondary losses. You'd want to fill your winding area as much as possible.

Comment: I can stuff it 3 times. Very snug but to much power. 2 is not enough.  What would happen if I increased my secondary 2 awg larger? Would 2 windings be enough then?

Comment: Can you add a photo?

Comment: Impossible for anyone but you to answer. You know your circuit's requirements, but we don't. Please update your question with your requirements. Please calculate your secondary resistance and losses.

Comment: With a shell type core, try two and a half turns: winding end on either side of core/pass one window twice, the other three times.

Comment: I don't have steady internet so I don't respond quickly. I'll take a pic and send soon. I'll also try 2.5 turns. And I'll calculate secondary resistance along with anything else that was suggested and get back here when I'm done. Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 2):

The voltage ratio from the primary to secondary is determined by how many times the transformer core goes through the middle of the wire, i.e. the number of turns. The wire size has no effect on this. 3 turns of thin wire is the same as 3 turns of thick wire.

The wire size *does* have an effect on the wire resistance. Thin wire has a higher resistance (i.e. less conductance) than thick wire. For the same amount of current, it generates more heat and drops more voltage. Therefore you want to use the thickest wire that you can fit, or afford.

Comment: I'm back and a little confused. What I am building is a spot welder for battery packs. I have great need of one but little currency and a lot of time. And I love doing this. I'm uploading pics, excuse safety violations. If it works, I'll put more money in it. I'm skeptical.

Comment: I'm having trouble uploading, ignorance on my part. I'll figure it out in a few minutes.

Comment: I stumbled onto this site looking for answers and I'm in over my head. You guys are so much more educated and experienced than I.  Even in your most basic levels. I can't include a picture for my question. I don't know how to code. Read or write it. I'm an electrical trade school grad with little traditional experience trying to do a project that is beyond my scope. But that's how I learn. I'm going to go educate myself some more. Thank you.

Comment: @DazeDaemar because you are a new user you do not have permission to upload images. If you upload an image on any website and add a link in the question, anyone who has a small amount of reputation can change it to a picture. Pictures can't go in comments no matter what, only links can. Anyone who has a small reputation could also take the link from a comment and put it in the question.

Comment: @DazeDaemar I am not sure which part of my answer wasn't understandable? Do you know what voltage, current and resistance are?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is impossible to answer without knowing more about the project. In particular you need to know how much current it will take through the battery terminals to generate the heat needed to weld them together. Bearing in mind that the transformer in a microwave will only be rated for maybe 700 watts as an intermittant load, the hope will be to transfer that energy as heat into the battery terminals for half a second or so to make the joint.
A typical transformer will have 7 or 8 turns of wire on the primary for each volt of the mains supply. Assuming the UK mains voltage of 230, it will draw roughly 3 amps for 700 watts. The secondary winding for whatever purpose will produce the same volts per turn, so just one may be sufficient, as long as the wire is thick enough to pass the current. If one turn produces 1/8 volt, 700 watts equates to 6800 amps, a huge current, which is often handled by using a flat strip of copper instead of wire.
Overall, you really need to understand the basic principles a lot better BEFORE you play with this sort of device.